# Getting the type of a wildcard object for Java method dispatch?

Tags: java, casting

I have a list of wildcard objects and want to keep the iteration algorithm separate from the item processing, which is dependent on the types of objects contained in the list.

What's the best way to determine the type of the `item` in the `items` *List* and dispatch to the appropriate `doSomething` method?

```
private void iterateListAlgo (List<?> items) {
  for (int i = 0, len = items.size(); i < len; i++) {
  //... lalala
    doSomething(items.get(i));
  }
}

private void doSomething (ClassA item) {
  //... lalala
}

private void doSomething (ClassB item) {
  //... lalala
}

// etc.
```

Compiling this gives me the error:

```
required: ClassA
  found: CAP#1
  reason: argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to ClassA
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

I'd prefer to keep the type casting out of the `iterateListAlgo` function, but I'm not even sure how to that much.

Comment: Is there any relation between `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Comment: If you want to get object type at runtime then reflection is probably a good place to start.

Comment: They have class-specific ways of extracting information about themselves, let's say a name, but don't do it in the same way.

Comment: @MarcusBooster I mean, relation in the sense, any common superclass of them, or common superinterface?

Comment: Just java.lang.Object. The items are from separate libraries.

Comment: @MarcusBooster Alas! Your only option now is `instanceof` check and appropriate cast afterwards. Better to create two different methods, and pass them `List<ClassA>` and `List<ClassB>` separately.

Comment: The canonical answer is "use the visitor pattern" - even if the items are from libraries, you can still use adapters that give them a common interface. Unfortunately Java does not support dynamic dispatch which would let you do this sanely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this in java is to have `ClassA` and `ClassB` implement a common interface which has the method `doSomething()`. E.g,

```
interface CanDoSomething {
    public doSomething();
}

class ClassA implements CanDoSomething {..}
class ClassB implements CanDoSomething {..}

private void iterateListAlgo(List<CanDoSomething> items) {
   for (CanDoSomething item : items) {
       item.doSomething();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer contains the anecdote for what the OP is trying to accomplish however doesn't answer their question, if you simply specify that they can use `instanceof` to figure out the type of a class and that it's bad practice, your answer will be complete.

Answer (score 2):

Using `instanceof` you can determine which class an object is:

```
if(items.get(i) instanceof ClassA)
    doSomething((ClassA)items.get(i));
```

edit: This is a possible solution, but the interface solution Hari Shankar posted is a much cleaner and better way to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a if statement, and then have each block be based on

```
if(objA instanceof classA)
{
 \\Do Something to objA relevant to classA
}
elseif(objA instanceof classB)
{
 \\Do Something to ObjA but relevant to classB
}
```

Comment: From where do you get `.instanceOf`? And how would it work with `switch`?

Comment: The `.` and the `()` seems to indicate that `instanceOf` (with a capital `O`) is a method. The link you provided refers to a keyword (which btw can't be used in a switch). Downvoted your answer until you've provided a complete example.

Comment: Java has a type system that allows inheritance and overriding methods, given the former, this is a terrible solution for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Ben This is a reasonable solution if this is the only case in which the Classes would have to be used in the same loop. If such a comparison was to be required in other parts of the code then an interface would make sense and the answer above me is the same